# Subrayado o negrita como respuesta json

Tags: javascript, backend, nestjs

como estan?

Me preguntaba si había la forma de que mi back responda con negrita cierto fragmento de su return json

```
{
  "msg": "Shipment: SHI000000013 finalizó con errores!",
  "res": [
    {
      "code": 500,
      "reason": "Document not generated",
      "description": "One product has 0 'NetPrice' as a value",
      "timestamp": 1625593317200,
      "casuse": "One product has 0 'NetPrice' as a value"
    },
}
```

Por ejemplo, ese es una respuesta de mi back, me preguntaba si podía hacer que alguno de sus datos se muestren o subrayados o en negrita,
ej:

todo el objeto igual PERO la propiedad msg se muestre así:

`"msg": "Shipment: **SHI000000013** finalizó con errores!"`

Gracias!

Comment: Creo que es relevante que enseñes el código que tienes ahora para mostar. Igual es tema se centra en ese punto.

Comment: Pues el backend puede responder lo que tú le digas que responda y seguro puede armar el mensaje que tú le digas que arme. Lo que no sabemos es qué código crea ese mensaje y por qué tienes lío al armar un mensaje diferente.

Comment: espera.. vos queres que esa propiedad se muestre en negrita en donde?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a darle estilo a tu respuesta en consola?